# Ubuntu automatic update fails

Tags: package-management, 22.04, dependencies

This happened over night, when I turned my monitor on in the morning I saw this error pop up. I have no idea how it happened and I have only the slightest indication of what is happening (dependencies are broken, but not why they would be necessary). Anyone who could shine some light on my issue would be helpful and appreciated.

```
This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.
Transaction failed: Package dependencies cannot be resolved
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libqt5gui5-gles: Depends: libgbm1 (>= 8.1~0) but 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 is to be installed
                 Depends: libice6 (>= 1:1.0.0) but 2:1.0.10-1build2 is to be installed
                 Depends: libjpeg8 (>= 8c) but 8c-2ubuntu10 is to be installed
                 Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 11) but 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04 is to be installed
                 Depends: libudev1 (>= 183) but 249.11-0ubuntu3.9 is to be installed
                 Depends: libx11-xcb1 (>= 2:1.7.2) but 2:1.7.5-1ubuntu0.2 is to be installed
                 Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-3 but it is a virtual package
                 Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu9.2 is to be installed
```

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DGLX.png)

Answer (score 1):

Since the problem seems to be related to a previous update it is likely to be hardware agnostic, particularly as -gles is a version of Qt GUI library built against OpenGL ES, for use on embedded/mobile devices. I suspect a bug in the update to kernel version 6.x.x as I reverted to 5.19.0 and the problems disappeared. To try this answer you can select the previous kernel (not the recovery option) by quickly pressing and holding the Shift key at startup and selecting it from the options. If that clears the fault then use dpkg to remove the offending package, e.g. https://recoverit.wondershare.com/linux-recovery/dpkg-uninstall.html